# Help in understanding proof of theorem 2.14 in Friedberg's linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The theorem is: Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces with ordered basis $B=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_m\}$ and $C=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ respectively and let $T:V\to W$ be linear.Then, for each $u\in V$, we have $$[T(u)]_C=[T]_B^C[u]_B \tag 1$$

The proof is this: Fix $u\in V$ and define linear maps $f: F\to V$ by $f(x)=xu$ and $g:F\to W$ by $g(x)=xT(u)$ for all $x\in F$. Let $\alpha=\{1\}$ be the standard ordered basis for $F$. Notice that $g=Tf$. Identifying column vectors as matrices and using theorem 2.11 (refer **Note**), we obtain $$[T(u)]_C=[g(1)]_C=[g]_\alpha^C=[Tf]_\alpha^C=[T]_B^C[f]_\alpha^B=[T]_B^C[f(1)]_B=[T]_B^C[u]_B\tag 2$$

I don't understand why 2nd equality in $(2)$ is correct. Please help. Thanks.

**Note:** Let $V,W,Z$ be finite dimensional vector spaces with bases $B,C,D$ respectively and let $T:V\to W$ and $U:W\to Z$. Then, $[UT]_B^D=[U]_C^D[T]_B^C.$

Comment: How are entries of matrices defined in this book? For instance, how does the book define the entry $(n, m)$ of $[T]^C_B$?

Comment: The matrix $[g]_{\alpha}^C$ is the coordinate matrix of the linear transformation $g$ relative to the bases $\alpha$ and $C$. It is an $n\times 1$ matrix, whose unique column is the coordinate vector of  value of $g$ at the unique element of $\alpha$, in terms of the basis $C$. That is, the unique column of $[g]_{\alpha}^C$ is the coordinate vector of $g(1)$ in terms of $C$, which is precisely what $[g(1)]_C$ is.

Comment: @GabrielC.Barbosa: For every $1\le j\le m$ there exist $a_{ij}$'s such that $Tv_j= \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ji} w_i$. $a_{ji}$ is defined as $(i,j)$th entry of the matrix $[T]_B^C$.

Comment: It feels the main question is how $[g]^C_\alpha$ is defined precisely. The answer to your question should follow immediately.

Comment: @GabrielC.Barbosa: $[T]_{B}^C$ is the coordinate matrix from $B$ to $C$. The $(n,m)$ entry is the coefficient of $w_n$ (the $n$th vector of $C$) when expressing $T(v_m)$ (the $m$th vector of $B$) in terms of $C$.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked to be sure I could say something about the (single) column of $[g]^C_\alpha$, which justifies the equality given this definition.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. $g$ is a linear map from $F$ to $W$ and matrix associated to $g$ is $[g]_\alpha^C$. How do we get that matrix? By writing $g(1)$ as linear combination of vectors in $C$. That is, $[g(1)]_C= [g]_\alpha^C$. Thank you all. :)